# Used space of a disk is much larger than the size on disk of all files on that disk

Tags: windows-10, window, disk-space

I show the properties of D: disk and the used space is 193GB but when i select all files on disk D: and show properties, it displays 92.5GB size on disk.
Please help me explain that.

[image: Disk properties showing 193GB and file properties showing 92.5GB]

I tried to clean up the disk and delete all files on recycling bin but nothing changed. I'm using window 10.

Comment: Maybe there are hidden files and folders you are not selecting?

Comment: thank you guys. i did select all hidden files and folders

Comment: You might not have permissions to see all folders and therefore this would be the result.  Example?  If I install games through "XBox Ultimate", Windows decided that those should be on "D:" .. those files ARE HUGE.. the default is to not let my user account see them directly.  "Something" is sitting there outside of your user permissions AND OR "Something" is using NTFS alternate data streams are eating up the space.

Comment: Windows File Explorer can NOT be relied on to give you accurate information on files and folders, especially their sizes. Even such basic things as file names are often misrepresented in Explorer.

Comment: thank you guys so much